# Cannot see On-Premise Gateway for SharePoint 2019

Tags: sharepoint-server, powerapp, 2019, ms-flow

I have installed On-Premises Data Gateway on SharePoint 2019 server. 
The connections results are succeeded as shown below:

[image]

However, when I'm trying to create connections in MS Flow or PowerApps, I'm not able to find the installed Gateway:

[image]

Note:

1. I'm using the same account to create connection, the one I used
   while configuring the gateway.
2. I have also tried with PowerBI Gateway installer, still same result.
3. Also, P2 license is assigned to the user account trying to create connection and configuration.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: If you go into Flow -> gear icon -> Gateways, do you see it registered there?

Comment: It's not showing in the "Gateways".

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you haven't properly installed and registered the gateway with the service. Make sure you have the Power Automate/PowerApp/Power BI administrator role as this will be required to register the gateway in non-personal mode.

You also should also be installing the gateway on a dedicated server.

Since your original post doesn't have enough information to fully assist you, I suggest you read the [documentation on the gateway](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-gateway-onprem-indepth), especially [troubleshooting](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-gateway-onprem-tshoot).

Comment: I found that there are different environments (default, production etc.) in our tenant. 
Earlier, the user that we configured for Gateway had permission only to default environment. 
After the permission was granted to Production environment, it was found that all the previous Gateways Registrations were visible. 
Can you tell how the Gateway can be registered to a specific environment?